# how to iterate json value to draw polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I m trying to auto draw a polygon using stored values from database. My python file returns json result to the ajax call. In ajax success part i want to iterate the json result data and then i want to auto draw polygon on google map.

My python file result looks like this

```
{u'poly1': ((47.5317790059, 7.70534455782), (47.5319557221, 7.70540356642), 
(47.5317892503, 7.70558059221), (47.5317790059, 7.70534455782)), u'poly2': 
((47.5321093878, 7.70504951483), (47.5321452431, 7.70517826086), (47.5319403555, 
7.70537674432), (47.5321093878, 7.70504951483))}
```

map initialized in another js file like this:

```
    my_map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map-canvas',
        lat: 47.53187912201915,
        lng: 7.705222390807307,
        zoom: 20,
        zoomControl : true,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'

    });
```

\Here GMaps is comes from another file called gmaps.js where all the google map functionality is defined.

In javascript file i have code some thing like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getPolygon",
    data: ({
        'id': id,
        'as_json': 1
    }),
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    // i want to loop through the data and then i want to pass the value to the path
    //poly1 should be like this
    // poly1 =[[47.5317790059, 7.70534455782],[47.5319557221, 7.70540356642],
    //          [47.5317892503, 7.70558059221],[47.5317790059, 7.70534455782]]
    //poly2=same like poly1
    var my_area;
    map = my_map;

    my_area = map.drawPolygon({
            paths: [poly1,poly2],
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
    },
    error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        } 

});
```

I Want to generate variables like poly1,poly2 dynamically depending up on the length of the data then the variables should be passed to the paths: for drawing polygon. Can anyone help in this.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Cerbrus: it's a python map actually

Comment: @@Cerbus: Do you understand what i m trying to do?

Comment: @@zerkms:Do you also understand what i m trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using that returned `data` object:

```
var my_area = map.drawPolygon({
        paths: [data.poly1, data.poly2],
        // ...
```

or if you have more than two polygons:

```
var i = 1;
var paths = [];
while (data['poly'+i]) {
    paths.push(data['poly'+i]);
    i++;
}
var my_area = map.drawPolygon({
        paths: paths
        // ...
```

since your object would be JSON-dumped like this (e.g. with `simplejson`):

```
{"poly2": [[47.5321093878, 7.70504951483], [47.5321452431, 7.70517826086], [47.5319403555, 7.70537674432], [47.5321093878, 7.70504951483]], "poly1": [[47.5317790059, 7.70534455782], [47.5319557221, 7.70540356642], [47.5317892503, 7.70558059221], [47.5317790059, 7.70534455782]]}
```

Comment: @@antoine129: ostapische script worked when i use the google map directly.I tried it in a plain html page. Just now i started to use in my project and i have to find way to use my predefind map. i mean map.drawPolygon

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/UD567/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {  
    width: 400px;  
    height: 400px;  
}
```

**JS**

```
$( function() {
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng( 47.5317892503, 7.70558059221 );
    var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);
    var result = "{ u'poly1': ( ( 47.5317790059, 7.70534455782 ), ( 47.5319557221, 7.70540356642 ), ( 47.5317892503, 7.70558059221 ), ( 47.5317790059, 7.70534455782 ) ), u'poly2': ( ( 47.5321093878, 7.70504951483 ), ( 47.5321452431, 7.70517826086 ), ( 47.5319403555, 7.70537674432 ), ( 47.5321093878, 7.70504951483 ) ) }";
    /* var coords = { "poly1": [
        [ 47.5317790059, 7.70534455782],
        [ 47.5319557221, 7.70540356642 ],
        [ 47.5317892503, 7.70558059221 ],
        [ 47.5317790059, 7.70534455782 ]
    ], "poly2":  [
        [ 47.5321093878, 7.70504951483 ],
        [ 47.5321452431, 7.70517826086 ],
        [ 47.5319403555, 7.70537674432 ],
        [ 47.5321093878, 7.70504951483 ]
    ] }; */
    var coords = JSON.parse( result.replace( /u/g, "" ).replace( /'/g, '"' ).replace( /\(/g, "[" ).replace( /\)/g, "]" ) );
    var path;
    var polygon;
    for ( var poly in coords ) {
        console.log( poly );
        path = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < coords[ poly ].length; i ++ ) {
            console.log( coords[ poly ][ i ] );
            path.push( new google.maps.LatLng( coords[ poly ][ i ][ 0 ], coords[ poly ][ i ][ 1 ] ) );
        }
        polygon = new google.maps.Polygon( {
            paths: path,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        } );
        polygon.setMap( map );
    }
} );
```

[polygon-simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)

Comment: @@ostapische: How can i format my data in success: function (data) like yours var coords={}. data is from my python file result

Comment: @@ostapische: is there any way to use my pre-defined map instead of new google.maps.LatLng

Comment: @@ostapische: i defined my map in another file so i would like to use the old one. i dont want to use new google.maps.LatLng,instead i would like to use map(coords...)

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir if you define `map` in another file in **global scope**, then you can use it in any script. About `data`: what is `console.log( data );` in `ajax` `success` function writes in console?

Comment: @@ostapische: About data: i changed json as data string using JSON.Stringyfy. so its not a problem now. I have problem with the map

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir can you show me how you initialize map in another file? And if you use `dataType: "json"` then in my code `var coords` equals to your `data` in `ajax` `success` function and you do not need to use `JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse` and `replace` functions.

Comment: @@ostapische: I Updated my post .Look at it pls.

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir if `my_map = ...` not in any function, then you can use variable `my_map` in any place, no need to do `map = my_map`, just use `my_map.drawPolygon...` or something else. And place `var` before `my_map = ...`. If `my_map` in function then in the biginning of `gmaps.js` file place `var my_map;` and `my_map` will be accesible in any place. But any manupulations  with map must be after initialization, just place `gmaps.js` file in the beginnig of the `HEAD` section.

Comment: @@ostapische:I used my_map(coords..)i get error my_map is not a function. what do i have to use instead of new google.maps.LatLng(coords....)? i m confussed

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir yeah, you get that error cause `my_map` is not a function, it's variable. You must use `new google.maps.LatLng` function or in any way.